# Don't understand the use of order() on both numerics and characters

Tags: r

```
rankhospital<- function(state, outcome, num = "best")
{
  outcome1 <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",
                   colClasses = "character")
 if(!any(state == outcome1$State)){
 stop("invalid state")}
 else if((outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure",
                      "pneumonia")) == FALSE) {
 stop(print("invalid outcome"))
  }
 outcome2 <- subset(outcome1, State == state)
 if (outcome == "heart attack") {
 colnum <- 11
  }
 else if (outcome == "heart failure") {
 colnum <- 17
  }
 else {
 colnum <- 23
 }
 outcome2[ ,colnum] <- as.numeric(outcome2[ ,colnum])
 **outcome3 <- outcome2[order(outcome2[ ,colnum],outcome2[,2]), ]**
 outcome3 <- outcome3[(!is.na(outcome3[ ,colnum])),]
 if(num == "best"){
  num <- 1
  }            
   else if (num == "worst"){
   num <- nrow(outcome3)
    }      
   return(outcome3[num,2])
  }

  # example output:
   > rankhospital("NC", "heart attack", "worst")
   > [1] "WAYNE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL"
```

Hi, I'm studing on this group of code which is designed for ranking the hospitals for states in US according to the death rate of three diseases, the lower the death rate, the better the hospital is. I was reading and studying the code and was stuck by the line of

```
       outcome3 <- outcome2[order(outcome2[ ,colnum],outcome2[,2]), ]
```

Basicly, in the dataset, column 11, 17 and 23 are the death rates for each of diseases, column 2 is "Hospital name", and column 7 is "State", which is the corresponding state for each hosiptal. The line of code that confuses me is to rank the death rate for a certain disease from min to max within a state, and give a order to the hospital names. But it doesn't make sense to me as the order function seems to rank the death rate - outcome2[ ,colnum] and hospital name - outcome2[,2] seperately, and if they are not corresponding to each other, then it is not meaningful as the outcome would not return the hospital name with ranking in death rate. But this line should be correct and worked to rank the death rate and the corresponding hospital name from min to max.
I hope someone could help me explain how this line of code operate to make it work.
Thank you soo much

Comment: When you give `order` multiple arguments, it sorts by the first argument first, then uses the 2nd as a tiebreaker, then the third, etc. You should check out the `?order` help page - go to the Examples section and the first example illustrates this.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, I get it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the upper comment, I got to read through the help page and saw how the example in it works. And just wanna do a explanation for this situation:

```
  outcome3 <- outcome2[order(outcome2[ ,colnum],outcome2[,2]), ]
```

In this line, `outcome2[ ,colnum]` is to output the death rate and `order()` will rank the data from min to max, while the rest of the rows in each column would also change position according to this new order. So for this case, there is no need to add hospital name which is the second column into `order()` as the argument.

However, in the ranking of data for death rate, there could be some data having the same value which means some hospitals possibly have the same death rate for a certain disease, therefore "hospital name" as the second argument of `order()` would rank the name from "a" to "z" within a concident death rate.

So the basic idea is that `order()` gives an order to data in one column(1st arg), and if there are coincident data occured, then `order()` will give an order to the second argument(another column) for that coincident data, and this will reposition the corrsponding data in other columns as well based on the order from argument 1.